# Split value of a column into different columns

Tags: r, dataframe, split, multiple-columns

I have a variable in a R data frame with this format, are are have a mixed format:

```
98 (56:78)
34 (45:67)
45
67 (34:98)
```

I want do divide that column into 3 values,and to put each value in a new column of the data frame.

```
98 56 78
34 45 67
45 NA NA
67 34 98
```

how can I do that? 
thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your sample data

```
dd <- data.frame(a=c("98 (56:78)", "45"))
```

You can do this using the tidyverse (and the tidyr package in particular) using

```
library(tidyverse)
dd %>% separate(a, c("x","y","z"), extra="drop")
#    x    y    z
# 1 98   56   78
# 2 45 <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you! But there is a problem and I think is bc my variable is considered as a factor, and it gives me the following error: Error in Math.factor(var) : ‘abs’ not meaningful for factors, any idea how to fit it?

Comment: It would help if you provided a more complete [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your original question. I've tested the code I wrote and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Well, I have realized that not all the values in my data are in the same format some are 'a(b:c)' and some are 'a'.

Comment: That still works with my code. I don't get the error you describe. You just get a warning about the incomplete split

Answer (score 0):

Here is a longer base R method that returns a nice looking data.frame.

```
setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame,
                 regmatches(temp, regexec("(\\d+) \\((\\d+):(\\d+)\\)$", temp)))[-1],
         paste0("V", 1:3))
```

Here, `regexec` selects the desired numbers using the regular expression "(\d+) \((\d+):(\d+)\)$" and `regmatches` returns a list of length equal to its inputs with each element a length of 4. This list is turned into a data.frame with `do.call` and `rbind.data.frame` and the first column, which contains the full string, is removed. Finally, `setNames` replaces the ugly default names with more manageable ones.

This returns

```
  V1 V2 V3
1 98 56 78
2 91 53 76
3 99 53 75
```

Note that the variables are factor variables in this context, which are usually not very useful. To convert these to numeric, you can use the  `dat[] <- lapply(dat, as.numeric)` paradigm.

**data**

```
temp <- c("98 (56:78)", "91 (53:76)", "99 (53:75)")
```

Answer (score 0):

A tidy solution using `extract()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(a = c("98 (56:78)", "10"))

df %>%
  extract(a, into = c("x", "y", "z"), regex = "(\\d*) ?\\(?(\\d*):?(\\d*)") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(x, y, z), as.integer)
```

Which results in:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      x     y     z
  <int> <int> <int>
1    98    56    78
2    10    NA    NA
```